# Bourbon Neat -- Is outer-container necessary?

Tags: bourbon, neat

I am wondering if `@include outer-container` is necessary?

I've noticed that the behavior ( at the surface ) is the same with or without. However, I realize that there are possible implications to assuming this.

---

**page.html** *with outer-container*

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "box"></div>
</div>
```

**page.scss** *with outer-container*

```
.container {
    @include outer-container;
    .box {
        @include span-columns(6);
    }
}
```

---

**page.html** *without outer-container*

```
<div class = "box"></div>
```

**page.scss** *without outer-container*

```
.box {
    @include span-columns(6);
}
```

Both of these result in the same effect of creating a div with the width of half the page. So, is `@include outer-container` necessary or no?

What are the possible implications of not using this?

Answer (score 0):

Referencing the Neat docs:

> Although optional, using outer-container is recommended

It clears floats, centers the container in the viewport and sets a max width. The following:

```
.element {
    @include outer-container(100%);
  }
```

Would output this:

```
.element {
    *zoom: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  .element:before, .element:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
  }

  .element:after {
    clear: both;
  }
```

Personally I always use them, as you will need some sort of container to place your `span-columns` in